# QT4.8.6 and Visual Studio 2010 doesnt load google maps

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-maps, qt4

I am using QtCreator 4.8.6 on Windows 7, compiler MSVC2010.
The issue is when I run the application, it works, however, it doesn’t load map data from Google maps in WebView, it shows blank. Ironically the URL when viewed in any other web browser displays Maps successfully.
I also tried to load Google or Nokia web page, I was unsuccessful, but couldnt open google maps. I would really appreciate if someone could help me to resolve this issue?
Its a request.

Regards and Thanks in Advance,
Rahul

Comment: Can you improve the question with some code?

Comment: my code

Mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->webView->setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com/maps"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

Comment: Mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebView>
#include <QUrl>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();  
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the WebView to use the latest version of IE.  See:

- [Issue 6550: Bug: Map doesn't render correctly in a WebBrowser object](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6550)
- [Issue 9004: Bug: Javascript error - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/23/2/intl/en_gb/onion.js](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9004)

from [a link in issue 9004](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation):

> **Browser Emulation**
>
> Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. The FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION feature defines the default emulation mode for Internet Explorer and supports the following values.
>
> Value Description
>
> 11001 (0x2AF9 Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
>
> 11000 (0x2AF8)    IE11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11.
>
> 10001 (0x2711)    Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> 10000 (0x02710)   Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
>
> 9999 (0x270F) Windows Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
>
> 9000 (0x2328) Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
>   Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
>
> 8888 (0x22B8) Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.
>
> 8000 (0x1F40) Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
>   Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
>
> 7000 (0x1B58) Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.

Comment: my code works fine when I use QtCreator 3.6.0 and Qt 4.8.6. QWebView is able to load the URL, but when i use same code in Visual Studio 2010, it doesn't load googlemaps URL but is able to open other URL like www.google.com or www.here.com or so on